# Endless problems with a very simple python subprocess.Popen task

Tags: python, subprocess

I'd like python to send around a half-million integers in the range 0-255 each to an executable written in C++. This executable will then respond with a few thousand integers. Each on one line. This seems like it should be very simple to do with subprocess but i've had endless troubles. Right now im testing with code:

```
// main()
u32 num;
std::cin >> num;

u8* data = new u8[num];
for (u32 i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    std::cin >> data[i];

// test output / spit it back out
for (u32 i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;

return 0;
```

Building an array of strings ("data"), each like "255\n", in python and then using:

```
output = proc.communicate("".join(data))[0]
```

...doesn't work (says stdin is closed, maybe too much at one time). Neither has using proc.stdin and proc.stdout worked. This should be so very simple, but I'm getting constant exceptions, and/or no output data returned to me. My Popen is currently:

```
proc = Popen('aux/test_cpp_program', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
```

Advise me before I pull my hair out. ;)

Comment: Are you sending the number of data items as the first number?

Comment: yep - cpp code shows that, forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, when you read a `char` or `unsigned char` from `cin`, it reads a single byte from `stdin`. However, you expect it to read a decimal representation of a number from 0 to 255. If you read an `int` instead it should read it correctly:

```
unsigned int n;
std::cin >> n;
data[i] = static_cast<u8>(n);
```

Or instead, you can have the Python code write the values as a sequence of bytes rather than digits, by using the `chr` function.

Comment: Yep. Right on the money! Wasn't thinking that istream::operator>> would treat char's special and that's what I was using for my u8.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int num;
    std::cin >> num;

    char* data = new char[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        std::cin >> data[i];

    // test output / spit it back out
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

python:

```
In [9]: from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
In [10]: a = Popen('./a.out', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
In [11]: a.stdin.write("2\nab")
In [12]: a.stdout.read()
Out[12]: 'a\nb\n'
```

Note that I added a delimiter (\n) between the number of bytes to write, this is the safest if you do not want your c++ cin to fail on sending something like 3,1,2,3 which would concatenate to 3123, expecting so many arguments.

Comment: Ah. A simple case of being too close to see the problem. I believe my C++ was looking at input like "4\n255\n34\n129\n0\n" and interpreting it as (char)'2', (char)'5', (char)'5', (char)'3', and then running to completion and closing. When python tried sending more data it threw an exception. All is well now. Thanks greatly for your help!